# Limits on number of used pointers in Queue implementation

Tags: pointers, data-structures

This is a question from the last years exam in my Data Structures course..
So, a Queue (data structure) consisting of n elements is implemented using pointers. The question is to find the maximum and minimum number of pointers used in that data structure?

So, I don't really understand where to start with this. I know the implementation of Queue using pointers. From it, I guess we only need two pointers, one for Front and Rear, which may be the minimum.
On the other hand, the elements of the Queue are cells that contain pointers on the next element, so there should be n+1 pointers?

Would be grateful for a nice explanation of this..or at least a hint if nothing else?

Comment: anyone?? please..

Comment: perhaps look at some of the functions queues have and determine how many unique pointers you would need to implement it